# Emacs major mode for emerald. Correct highlighting

Tags: emacs, comments, syntax-highlighting, major-mode

Long story short:

I am a student and in one of my courses we have to use/learn the [emerald programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emerald_%28programming_language%29). After a quick google search I found that somebody already wrote a major-mode for it. [Link to the script](http://simon.nitro.dk/dotfiles/emacs/emerald-mode.el)

**The problem:** After the first comment line "%...", syntax highlighting stops. So all subsequent lines are without any syntax highlighting. Which is extremely anoying.

Emerald doesn't have multi line comments. Only one line comments are part of the language syntax. A one line comment starts with "%" and ends with the end of line.

I am a complete newb to the whole major-mode, writing lisp scripts for emacs...etc.

**Question:** Can anyone help me figure out what exacly goes wrong with the syntax highlighting ? Why does it stop after the first one line comment? And how to fix it ?

**Other quick question:**
How do I make emacs highlight the other language keywords ? For example object, export, operation, function...etc ?

Thanks in advance :)

Edit: Here is a simple hello world test program to demonstrate syntax highlighting :

```
%this object pronts a hello message on screen
const hello <- object hello
  var n : integer <-  0

  operation gs[] -> [ret: integer]
    n <- n + 1
    ret <- n
    return
  end gs

  % a comment
  % second comment
  % third comment
  initially
    stdout.putstring["Hello World!\n"]
  end initially
end hello
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The first question:** You can single-step the font-lock keywords using the https://github.com/Lindydancer/font-lock-studio package. The problem could either be in one of the font-lock keywords, or in the syntax table (which is used to highlight comments and strings). If, after you start `font-lock-studio` (i.e. before any font-lock keywords are applied), the highlighting is incorrect, then the problem is with the syntax table.

**The second question:** You can call `font-lock-add-keywords` in a major mode hook to add new font-lock keywords. See the variable `font-lock-keywords` for a description on the format. However, the description is somewhat cryptic, so I would also recommend you to search the net for good examples.

**Update:** After installing `emerald-mode` I could replicate the problems that you saw. The root cause is that the mode implements core Emacs functions in a non-compatible way (the one provided with Emacs taked up to three arguments). If you delete the following function and restarts Emacs, font-locking appears to be working.

```
(defun looking-back (regexp)
  "Simulates a looking-at, but works backwards"
  (and (save-excursion
     (re-search-backward regexp (min (point-min) (- (point) 100)) t))
       (= (point) (match-end 0))))
```

Note that I could not have found this without `font-lock-studio`, as normal font-lock silently ignores errors whereas `font-lock-studio` enters the lisp debugger (if `debug-on-error` is non-nil).

**Update 2**: It appears that `emerald-mode` defines a set of font-lock keywords, but never adds them. If you add the following lines to your init file, it seems to work:

```
(defun my-emeral-mode-hook ()
  (setq font-lock-defaults '(emerald-font-lock-keywords nil t))
  (font-lock-mode 1))
(add-hook 'emerald-mode-hook 'my-emeral-mode-hook)
```

I noticed that `emerald-mode` is in a dire need of removation. For example, the major mode does not call `kill-all-local-variables`, which mean that it keeps all local variables from the previous major mode. (An even better solution would be to use `define-derived-mode` rather than defining the mode using a plain `defun`.) It sets `font-lock-keywords-case-fold-search` as a global variable and not via `font-lock-defaults` etc.

Comment: Thanks I will have a look at it tonight when I get back from school :)

Comment: I don't quite understand the part where  you explained weather the problem is in the syntax table or not.
Here is my situation:
I have this in my .emacs file:
(load "~/Downloads/font-lock-studio-master/font-lock-studio.el")
(load "~/.emacs.d/lisp/emerald-mode.el")
and the syntax coloring is wrong because of loadign the emerald-mode.el
Now. I do start font-lock-studio by M-x font-lock-studio, and it splits my screen but the syntax highlighting is already wrong before that.

Comment: Also when I have both font-lock and emerald-mode loaded at start, I run emacs, then M-x font-lock-studio I get the following error:
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-number-of-arguments (lambda (regexp) "Simulates a looking-at, but works backwards" (and (save-excursion (re-search-backward regexp (min (point-min) (- (point) 100)) t)) (= (point) (match-end 0)))) 3)
  looking-back("" 78 t)
  font-lock-fontify-syntactically-region(#<marker at 1 in *scratch*> #<marker (moves after insertion) at 192 in *scratch*>)
...

Comment: Yes now it doesn't mess up other mode's syntax coloring thanks :) But it doesn't syntax color emerald source at all. From what I understand of the font-lock system, emerald-mode.el defines the syntax highlighting in emerald-font-lock-keywords, but they don't work. Any ideas ? (I will include a test hello world program.)

Comment: I added the block that you mentioned in the emerald-mode.el and syntax coloring works to some degree for now. Thanks for the help :)

I will have to look into where I can insert the kill-all-local-variables so it doesn't retain the syntax coloring from Objective C or whatever else is loaded.